# Jquery addClass not working inside shadowbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, shadowbox

I need to add a class to a div inside a shadowbox and I am using jQuery to do this.

```
  jQuery("#all_records #"+id).addClass("selectedDiv");
```

In such circumstances, I usually check if I am calling the right div, and in this case it turns out I am. But unfortunately, it is never adding the class to the div.

```
 <div id="all_records">
 <div id="50157186" class="records_dealer_activation" onclick="select_customer(50157186);">
 </div>
 </div>



function select_customer(id){


        jQuery('#sb-player #choosen_customer_activation_duplicate').prepend('<div class="overlay">             <div class="modalprogress">                 <div class="theprogress"> <img class="image_load"  src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/progress_bar.gif" alt="loadanimation" /></div>             </div>         </div> ');



            jQuery("#sb-player #choosen_customer_activation_duplicate").load("<?php echo site_url().'/'.$main_controller;?>"+"/load_show_selected_customer_activation/?customerID="+id+"&type=duplicate");




            if(jQuery("#all_records > div").hasClass("selectedDiv"))
            {
                //THIS IS WORKING
                jQuery("#all_records > div").removeClass("selectedDiv");
            }
            //NOT WORKING
            //alert(jQuery("#sb-player #all_records #"+id).html());
            //document.getElementById(id).className += "selectedDiv";
            jQuery("#all_records #"+id).addClass("selectedDiv");



    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: As long as your id is being selected correctly, use chrome developer tools for this, this `$("#all_records#" + id).addClass("selectedDiv");` should work fine.

Comment: Can you step through this in Firebug / Chrome dev tools and see if something else is removing that style?

Comment: There's no need to do a selector like that.  If `"#" + id` is in fact a valid ID on your page, you should only need `jQuery("#" + id)` since an ID is unique.  All that said, it sounds like your selector is incorrect, and that is why no class is getting applied.  Please post up your HTML.

Comment: I have tried with jQuery("#"+id), but it does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your javacript function, btw this work for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function select_customer(id){
        jQuery("#" +id).addClass("selectedDiv");
    }
</script>
<div id="all_records">
 <div id="50157186" class="records_dealer_activation" onclick="select_customer(50157186);">
 Click me
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: div is inside a shadowbox, just to clarify